# Portrait Camera Images when Uploaded via Library rotates in ImageView Android

Tags: android, imageview, exif

In my Android App, I have an option where a user can take his photograph or upload an image from his Gallery at the time of registration. This image, once successfully taken by camera or selected from Gallery, is shown in an ImageView. Below is the onClick of ImageView code that starts this process.

This is from Activity Layout.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgUserImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:onClick="changePicture"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image_not_provided"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

This is from Activity.java

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgUserImage);

    int exif_orn_a;

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        imgProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        imgProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(mphoto);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mphoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bitmap is required image which have to send  in Bitmap form
        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};

        Bitmap lphoto = null;

        Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, orientationColumn, null, null, null);

        int orientation = -1;

        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
            orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));

            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Picture Orientation "+orientation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Wrong Orientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (cur != null) cur.close();

        try {
            lphoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

            imgProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImage);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            lphoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bitmap is required image which have to send  in Bitmap form
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have managed to get the Orientations properly. Now the problem is, how should I rotate the image before `imgProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImage);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. Please feel free to post a better solution, if you think this can be improvised.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ImageView imgProfilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgUserImage);

        int exif_orn_a;

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imgProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImage);

            imgProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(mphoto);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mphoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bitmap is required image which have to send  in Bitmap form
            byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
        else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            //Starting from here, I am checking the Orientation and storing the result in orientation variable.
            String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};

            Bitmap lphoto = null;

            Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, orientationColumn, null, null, null);

            int orientation = -1;

            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));

                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Picture Orientation "+orientation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Wrong Orientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            if (cur != null) cur.close();
            //This is the end of Orientation Check.

            try {
                lphoto = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);

                imgProfilePicture.setImageURI(selectedImage);


                //Based on the Orientation Check result, I rotate the ImageView Image to make it straight.
                if (orientation == 270) {
                    imgProfilePicture.setRotation(-90);
                } else if (orientation == 0) {
                    imgProfilePicture.setRotation(0);
                }
                //This is the end of Image Rotation based on the Orientation Check Result.

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                lphoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bitmap is required image which have to send  in Bitmap form
                byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```